# IdentityId is Nil Using AWS Cognito and Facebook Login in iOS App

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I have an app that is successfully logging in using the Facebook provider through AWS Cognito.  While using the app directly after logging in the identity can be retrieved and everything seems to be working great.

However, after some amount of time (approximately > 1 hour) when coming back into the app the identity id does not seem to be filled out.  What is weird is that the user name is still filled out - just not the id.

```
    let identity = self.getLoggedInIdentity()
    let id = identity?.identityId      //this is nil
    let username = identity?.userName  //this still has a value

    func getLoggedInIdentity() -> AWSIdentityManager? {
        if userIsLoggedIn() {
            return AWSIdentityManager.defaultIdentityManager()
        }

        return nil
    }

    func userIsLoggedIn() -> Bool {
        let identityManager = AWSIdentityManager.defaultIdentityManager()
        return identityManager.loggedIn
    }
```

I started with the AWS sample app, including the AWSMobileHubHelper framework that is automatically generated by the AWS Mobile Hub.

I believe the issue is that the session is not being resumed successfully as the completion block inside this function never fires after relaunching the app:

```
func didFinishLaunching(application: UIApplication, withOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    print("didFinishLaunching:")

    if (!isInitialized) {
        print("AWSIdentityManager Attempt Resume Session")
        AWSIdentityManager.defaultIdentityManager().resumeSessionWithCompletionHandler({(result: AnyObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                print("AWSIdentityManager Resume Session Result: \(result) \n Error:\(error)")
        })
        isInitialized = true
    }
    let didFinishLaunching: Bool = AWSIdentityManager.defaultIdentityManager().interceptApplication(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

    return didFinishLaunching
}
```

I have verified the function is being called upon relaunching the app and the resumeSessionWithCompletionHandler is being called but the completion handler is never fired and I assume the session is not being resumed successfully.

For reference here are the initial login functions as well:

```
@IBAction func handleFacebookLogin(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.handleLoginWithSignInProvider(AWSFacebookSignInProvider.sharedInstance())
}

func handleLoginWithSignInProvider(signInProvider: AWSSignInProvider) {
    AWSIdentityManager.defaultIdentityManager().loginWithSignInProvider(signInProvider, completionHandler: {(result: AnyObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        // If no error reported by SignInProvider, discard the sign-in view controller.
        if error == nil {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
            })
        }
        print("result = \(result), error = \(error)")
    })
}
```

Any ideas why I would be able to login initially and connect to other AWS services, but not be able to resume the session after some time has passed?

Comment: Can you share the implementation of `- getLoggedInIdentity` and the definition of the `identity` object? How are you getting the Cognito IdentityId from the SDK?

Comment: I modified the post to include the getLoggedInIdentity function as well as the functions that do the initial login.  The identity object is an optional of type AWSIdentityManager which is a wrapper object in the AWSMobileHubHelper framework.

Comment: How about the definition of `- userIsLoggedIn`? We need to see the entire login flow so that we can try reproducing the issue you are seeing.

Comment: I added the - userIsLoggedIn function as well

Comment: I have discovered that if I take out any interaction with DynamoDB the session will remain active.  Whenever there is interaction with DynamoDB it works after login for approximately <1 hour but then I start getting unauthenticated access exceptions and the identityId is nil.  Any direction this might provide?

Comment: The version of `AWSCore` and `AWSDynamoDB` need to match. The latest version of the AWS Mobile SDK for iOS distributed through CocoaPods and [our website](https://aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdk/) is 2.3.6. The AWS Mobile Hub uses a pre-released version of 2.4.0. `AWSIdentityManager` depends on `AWSCore` 2.4.0, and `AWSDynamoDB` 2.4.0 is not available to the public yet. So, for now, you cannot mix `AWSIdentityManager` and `AWSDynamoDB` in the same app. We are working on the 2.4.0 public release, but we do not have a timeframe we can share yet.

Comment: Based on my interactions with your guy's API, it is a version mess. Can I kindly ask that you guys get your versions of the various APIs all lined up? I tried using your cocoapods, but they weren't the latest, tried using frameworks, and those don't line up yet. Really need a consistent (ideally cocoapods) API that plays well together!!!

Comment: We've released the AWS Mobile SDK for iOS 2.4.0. It should resolve the version mismatch issue you encountered after initiating `AWSDynamoDB`. Also, you can now enable the DynamoDB (NoSQL) feature on AWS Mobile Hub console.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem.
I fixed like this on AppDelegate.
Did you implement this code?

```
    func application(application: UIApplication,openURL url: NSURL,sourceApplication: String?,annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```